# How to find ParentId files made by a specific user?

Tags: regex, xml

I hope this post will be clear and be accepted question with this phrasing (hope the new phrasing will finally be not closed and get an answer for).

I want to find all questions answered by a specific user (1000+ lines)  from a long xml file, below I show some lines from that XML, in which the last line (row id 19) is an answer given by user id 28 and it's an answer to the question in the first line (row id 13) . If you look on the last line, it says `ParentId="13"`.

```
<row Id="13" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T09:38:43.457" Score="4" ViewCount="142" Body="&lt;p&gt;one question;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" LastActivityDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;faq&gt;&lt;allowed-questions&gt;&lt;tags&gt;&lt;traditions&gt;" AnswerCount="3" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="14" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T10:53:37.200" Score="-3" Body="&lt;p&gt;another question.&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="106" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T10:53:37.200" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="15" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="7" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:00:53.940" Score="3" Body="&lt;p&gt;an answer/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="18" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:00:53.940" CommentCount="2" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />    
<row Id="16" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="11" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:07:20.333" Score="1" Body="&lt;p&gt;I answer.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="40" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:07:20.333" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" /> 
<row Id="17" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:31:36.430" Score="4" ViewCount="159" Body="&lt;p&gt;answer&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2014-10-10T19:58:18.847" LastActivityDate="2014-10-10T19:58:18.847" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;site-promotion&gt;&lt;beta&gt;" AnswerCount="4" CommentCount="2" FavoriteCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="18" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="13" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:51:11.940" Score="4" Body="&lt;p&gt;answer.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="18" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:51:11.940" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="19" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="13" CreationDate="2014-06-18T14:06:56.237" Score="13" Body="&lt;answer. &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="28" LastEditorUserId="-1" LastEditDate="2017-05-23T12:38:53.840" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T14:39:08.300" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
```

I am trying to find a search code which will find all questions answered by a specific user, in this example it's user 28 (which you can see in the last line close to the end it says OwnerUserId="28")     and the result of the search should be the first line :

```
<row Id="13" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T09:38:43.457" Score="4" ViewCount="142" Body="&lt;p&gt;one question;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" LastActivityDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;faq&gt;&lt;allowed-questions&gt;&lt;tags&gt;&lt;traditions&gt;" AnswerCount="3" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
```

Comment: And if you dont think regex is best used to find this questions , than please say what program is (not just what is not)

Comment: if you have freedom of choice in terms of tools of the trade, a solution could be surely parse that xml content using javascript and the browser apis, and then make xpath queries over the document abstracted. Regex have weakness when parsing data like that. Is that a possible way no hitting any constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Using [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom). it makes life easier.

#1 Main idea, find tag by attribute

```
document.querySelector('[attribute_name="find_value"]') -> find tag
```

Example

```
document.querySelector('[OwnerUserId="28"]') -> <row Id="19">
```

#2 Second idea, get attribute

```
find tag.getAttribute('ParentId') -> it's parentId 13
```

#3 Finally  find again by parent Id attribute

```
document.querySelector('[Id="13"]') -> <row Id="13">
```

Full code

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const response = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<row Id="13" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T09:38:43.457" Score="4" ViewCount="142" Body="&lt;p&gt;one question;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" LastActivityDate="2017-06-12T15:04:30.633" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;faq&gt;&lt;allowed-questions&gt;&lt;tags&gt;&lt;traditions&gt;" AnswerCount="3" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="14" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T10:53:37.200" Score="-3" Body="&lt;p&gt;another question.&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="106" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T10:53:37.200" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="15" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="7" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:00:53.940" Score="3" Body="&lt;p&gt;an answer/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="18" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:00:53.940" CommentCount="2" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />    
<row Id="16" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="11" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:07:20.333" Score="1" Body="&lt;p&gt;I answer.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="40" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:07:20.333" CommentCount="0" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" /> 
<row Id="17" PostTypeId="1" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:31:36.430" Score="4" ViewCount="159" Body="&lt;p&gt;answer&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="67" LastEditorUserId="254" LastEditDate="2014-10-10T19:58:18.847" LastActivityDate="2014-10-10T19:58:18.847" Title="title" Tags="&lt;discussion&gt;&lt;site-promotion&gt;&lt;beta&gt;" AnswerCount="4" CommentCount="2" FavoriteCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="18" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="13" CreationDate="2014-06-18T13:51:11.940" Score="4" Body="&lt;p&gt;answer.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="18" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T13:51:11.940" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
<row Id="19" PostTypeId="2" ParentId="13" CreationDate="2014-06-18T14:06:56.237" Score="13" Body="&lt;answer. &lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" OwnerUserId="28" LastEditorUserId="-1" LastEditDate="2017-05-23T12:38:53.840" LastActivityDate="2014-06-18T14:39:08.300" CommentCount="1" ContentLicense="CC BY-SA 3.0" />
`

function findId(dom, ownerUserId) {
    const parantId = dom.window.document.querySelector(`[OwnerUserId=\"${ownerUserId}\"]`).getAttribute('ParentId')
    return dom.window.document.querySelector(`[Id=\"${parantId}\"]`).getAttribute('Id')
}

const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(response);
const ownerUserId="28"
const foundId = findId(dom, ownerUserId)
console.log('final found ID: '   + foundId + ' by ' + ownerUserId + ' Owner User Id')
console.log('final found PostTypeId: ' + dom.window.document.querySelector(`[Id=\"${foundId}\"]`).getAttribute('PostTypeId'))
console.log('final found CreationDate: ' + dom.window.document.querySelector(`[Id=\"${foundId}\"]`).getAttribute('CreationDate'))
```

Result

```
$node find.js
final found ID: 13 by 28 Owner User Id
final found PostTypeId: 1
final found CreationDate: 2014-06-18T09:38:43.457
```